# Tick test for trade classification

Tags: r, if-statement, trading

Writing my master thesis, I have downloaded trading data:

```
  >head(Data1)
  PRICE PREVIOUS
1 100   99
2 98    100
3 100   98
4 100   100
5 100   100
6 101   100
```

The goal is to add a column that indicates if a trade was buyer ("buy") or seller ("sell") initiated. The rules are as follows:

- PRICE < PREVIOUS => Sell
- PRICE > PREVIOUS => Buy
- PRICE == PREVIOUS => Prior  classification

This is how it should look like

```
      >head(Data1)
     PRICE PREVIOUS TICK
    1 100   99       Buy
    2 98    100      Sell
    3 100   98       Buy
    4 100   100      Buy
    5 100   100      Buy
    6 101   100      Buy
```

I have written the following code:

```
Data1$TICK <- ifelse(Data1$PRICE == Data1$PREVIOUS, yes = shift(Data1[ ,3]), no = ifelse(Data1$PRICE>Data1$PREVIOUS, yes= "Buy", no = "Sell"))
```

However, when I try to execute the code I get the warning:

> Error in `[.data.frame`(Data1, , 3)` : undefined columns selected

Therefore I have two questions:

1. Is this code capable of delivering the result I would like to get?
2. What is the error message referring to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple way just using base.

```
data1 <- data.frame(PRICE = c(100,98,100,100,100,101), PREVIOUS = c(99,100,98,100,100,100))

tk <- c("Sell", NA, "Buy")[sign(data1$PRICE-data1$PREVIOUS)+2]
for(i in 2:length(tk)) if (is.na(tk[i])) tk[i] <- tk[i-1]

data1$TICK <- tk
print(data1)

#   PRICE PREVIOUS TICK
# 1   100       99  Buy
# 2    98      100 Sell
# 3   100       98  Buy
# 4   100      100  Buy
# 5   100      100  Buy
# 6   101      100  Buy
```

If you think it is more intuitive, you could have:

```
tk <- c("Sell", "Prior", "Buy")[sign(data1$PRICE-data1$PREVIOUS)+2]
for(i in 2:length(tk)) if (tk[i] == "Prior") tk[i] <- tk[i-1]
```

Comment: in base R: `transform(data1,m=ifelse(Reduce(function(x,y)ifelse(is.na(y),x,y),\`is.na<-\`(m<-sign(PRICE-PREVIOUS),m==0),accumulate = T)==1,"Buy","Sale"))`

Answer (score 1):

```
library(tidyverse)
dat%>%
  mutate(m = sign(PRICE-PREVIOUS),
         m=replace(m,m == 0,NA))%>%
  fill(m)%>%
  mutate(m = if_else(m==1,"Buy","Sale"))
  PRICE PREVIOUS    m
1   100       99  Buy
2    98      100 Sale
3   100       98  Buy
4   100      100  Buy
5   100      100  Buy
6   101      100  Buy
```